# Firebase onCall functions save the result to a variable in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I try to save result of calling firebase functions from Android app.My function works well, because I see result in log. But I can't save it into variable for further use. Any ideas?

```
public void getUserRankFromFirebase(){
        mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        String resultFBFunctions = "";

        mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("getUserOnCall")
                .call(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {

                            resultFBFunctions = httpsCallableResult.getData().toString();
                            Log.d("result1", httpsCallableResult.getData().toString()); //I see result here
                    }
                });
        Log.d("result2", resultFBFunctions); // No result here
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onSuccess()` is asynchronous. So, when are using the value of `resultFBFunctions`, it may be empty since the data is not retrieved yet...

The data retrieved is ought to be used inside the `onSuccess()` method itself

To solve your problem, use the data received inside the `onSuccess()` method itself

Please specify what is `resultFBFunctions` used for

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56747595/9652621) question may help you. Feel free to ask for clarifications